# Is this a undefined behaviour or normal output

Tags: c, gcc, sequence-points

This is a very simple question but even have some doubt in sequence point.

```
int a[3] = {1,2,4};
printf("%d",++a[1]);
```

### o/p

```
3
```

Is this a valid c statement, I am getting output `3`, which means it is same as

```
++(a[1])
```

But how is this possible as we have a pre-increment operator which has to increment the `a` first then the dereference has to happen.

Please correct my doubt. How we are getting `3`?

Comment: `a` is not even an assignable lvalue, so even if the precedence laws were different you could not get 4 . (you can't increment an array) (you cannot increment the numeric literal `1` either)

Comment: @wildplasserr : Ya got it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parentheses are right, your rationale for what you think should happen obviously wrong.

If you were right, and prefix-increment had higher priority than indexing, you would get a compiler-error for ill-formed code, trying to increment an array.

As-is, there's absolutely no chance for sequencing-errors or the like leading to UB.

Answer (score 7):

Behavior is well defined. Operator `[]` has higher precedence than prefix `++` operator. Therefore operand `a` will bind to `[]`. It will be interpreted as

```
printf("%d", ++(a[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how pre increment operator works. Its similar to `++count`. So here your value at a[1] (as [] has higher precendence than ++) get incremented and then its printed onto the console.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

The operator `[]` has a higher precedence then `++`